# on scroll set content at bottom of section when gone through that section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, position

I have several sections. each section I have a div with position `absolute`
when it's scrolling that div top position is updating it's ok.

Now I want when I complete scroll a specific section and try to scroll another section old section's div will fixed on that area where that section will end without hiding.

[Here is sample animation](https://i.imgur.com/7NU3oAO.gifv)
Here Is my code
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sy1c5bp7/)

```js
function active_menu_item(){

 var elements = ['#message', '#feature', '#course', '#education', '#facility', '#access', '#contact'];
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var top_of_element = $(element).offset().top;
        var top_set = top_of_screen - top_of_element + 50;
        var divHeight = $(element).height();
            
        if (top_of_element < top_of_screen) {
            $(element).find('.content_side_left').css('top', (top_of_screen - top_of_element + 50) + 'px');   
            
        }
    }
    
 }
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function(){
  //$(window).scroll(function() {
    active_menu_item();
});
```

```css
.content_item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:500px;
    background:gray;
    font-size:30px;
    
}
.content_side_left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
.content_side_left {
    width: 118px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="message" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="message" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="feature" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="course" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="education" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="facility" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="access" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to say, something like this? https://imgur.com/a/mw2qOWv

Comment: @WASD no, I want on scroll at end of a div and when will start to scroll another div. sticky content will stay at bottom of old div. and new div will follow as I implemented at top:10px

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you were looking for, the question seemed a bit vague. But provided I understood correctly, you want to keep the previously stuck item visible when you leave a "section" and affix the next sticky item below it. To do this I just kept track of the top position to stick to throughout the iteration of the loop and increased it for every stickied element I encountered. Code below:

```js
function active_menu_item(){
    //get all elements that are meant to be sticky
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.content_item .content_side_left');
    elements = [].slice.call(elements);//turn it into an array
    for(var element of elements){
      //reset all of the elements so we can calculate their natural position in the document
      element.style.position = "relative";
    }
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
    var top_position = 0;//track the place to stick the element
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        //get the position relative to viewport
        var top_of_element = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        
        var divHeight = $(element).height();
        //check to see if we are below the next "stick to" position
        if (top_of_element <= top_position) {
          element.style.position='fixed';
          element.style.top = top_position + 'px';
          top_position += divHeight;//increment the "stick to" position
            
        }
    }
    
 }
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function(){
  //$(window).scroll(function() {
    active_menu_item();
});
```

```css
.content_item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* z-index: 1;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    height:500px;
    background:gray;
    font-size:30px;
    
}
.content_side_left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.content_side_left {
    width: 118px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="message" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="message" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="feature" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="course" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="education" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="facility" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="access" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="content_item">    
    <div class="content_side_left" >
      sticky content
    </div>
</div>
```

You should be aware that performing this on every scroll event is going to be pretty bad for performance. Ideally you figure out some more clever way of caching the position and maybe throttle the events so you don't do this much work for every pixel the user scrolls. But hopefully this gives you an idea and helps you get started.

Comment: Sorry my bad I can't explain properly. yeah position will fixed for little time. when next div's top will come at top old div's sticky content will be hide

Comment: tx for your answer i got idea from ur answer and I solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't even need JS.

The last will obviously go over the other because of the overflow. But this can be fixed by changing top of each `div` either to squash or go above the top:

Try setting top from -390, -260, -130, 0, 130... and add more elements; or resize the window to something like 800px or less. The values would become negative once you know the content -- that's below your viewport height -- is being scrolled.

Open the following snippet in full size:

```css
.content_item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.content_side_left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 118px;
}

#message1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#message2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 130px;
}
#message3 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 260px;
}
#message4 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 390px;
}
#message5 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 550px;
}
#message6 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 680px;
}
#message7 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 810px;
}
```

```html
<div id="message1" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message2" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message3" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message4" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message5" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message6" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="message7" class="content_item">
      <div class="content_side_left">sticky content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry My bad I can't explain well. here is sample animation for one section. Hope u will get some idea about it. http://i.imgur.com/7NU3oAO.gifv   one hide another will display but without cutting by next div.